# If a category has both an initial and terminal object, does that mean they are the same object?

Tags: category-theory

If a category `C` has initial object `I` and terminal object `T`, then from what I read that means that `I` = `T`. From the definitions of initial and terminal objects, every object `A` has unique morphisms `I -> A`, and `A -> T`. But unless `I` and `T` are the same (zero) object, then won't `I` have a distinct morphism from `I -> A -> T` for every object `A` through composition?
I haven't found this mentioned anywhere so far so I just wanted to make sure I am reading the definitions correctly.

Comment: No....In $\mathbf {Sets}$ the empty set is initial, and every set with a single element is terminal.  Where did you read that initial and terminal objects had to coincide?

Comment: Or this category $\circlearrowright i\rightarrow f\circlearrowright$

Comment: I didn't read that they have to coincide I just can't figure out how they wouldn't. In your example what is the unique function from empty set to terminal in Set?

Comment: It's the usual injection of the empty subset into any set.  To stress:  there are, of course, a *lot* of terminal objects in that category.  Sure they are all naturally isomorphic, but they are not unique.

Comment: If you want a different sort of example, consider a fixed ordered set $\mathcal S$.  We can view $\mathcal S$ as a category with objects given by the elements of $\mathcal S$ and for which there is a (unique) morphism between two objects, $a,b\in \mathcal S$ if and only if $a≤b$.  Then $\mathcal S$ has a (unique) initial object if and only if it has a least element and it has a (unique) terminal object if and only if it has a greatest element.  These clearly don't coincide in general.

Comment: so the uniqueness of the morphism is only within the homset!

Comment: I don't understand.  Where else could an arrow be unique?

Comment: in your ordered set example, through composition couldn't you construct an arrow from the least to the greatest element?

Comment: I think you are confused.  If $I$ is an initial object then, by definition, we must have a (unique) arrow from $I$  to *any* other object in the category.  Similarly, if $T$ is terminal, we must have a unique arrow to $T$ from *any* other object in the category.  So of course there is a  unique arrow from $I$ to $T$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139534/discussion-between-david-hill-and-lulu).

Comment: In your "But unless `I` and `T` are the same (zero) object, then won't I have a distinct morphism from `I -> A -> T` for every object `A` through composition?" For some pair of objects `I` and `F` it might be that the compositions of morphisms passing through different `A` give different morphisms from `I` to `F`. However, if `I` and `F` are really going to be initial and final, respectively, they are all going to be the same composition, the unique `I->F`. It is part of the definition of being initial and final.

Comment: Choosing different objects $A$ is giving you differently presented morphisms $I \to T$, but if you actually do the composition you will get the same result. You look like your thinking of something that sometimes shows up in a more difficult case where instead of doing the composition you just treat it as a formal composition (it comes up when you don't quite have a category [A distillation of Wehrheim-Woodward](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1401.7302.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

> If a category $\mathcal{C}$ has initial object $I$ and terminal object $T$, then from what I read that means that $I = T$.

No, initial and terminal objects need not be the same.
Consider the following examples:

- Consider $\mathbf{Set}$.
  There exists a unique initial object in $\mathbf{Set}$, namely the empty set.
  The terminal objects in $\mathbf{Set}$ are precisely the singleton sets (i.e., those sets that contain precisely one element).
  But the empty set is not a singleton set.
- Consider the category $\mathbf{Ring}$ of rings.
  The initial object of $\mathbf{Ring}$ is $ℤ$, and the terminal object is the zero ring.
  These two rings are very much not the same.
- Let $P$ be a partially ordered set, considered as a category in the usual way.¹
  An initial object of $P$ is the same as a minimum of $P$, and a terminal object of $P$ is the same as a maximum of $P$.
  Unless $P$ consists of only a single element, these two will not be the same.

We have in the given arbitrary category $\mathcal{C}$ a unique morphism from $I$ to $T$.
(This hold because $I$ is initial, and it also holds because $T$ is terminal.)
However, the reverse is not necessarily true:
there does not need to exist a morphism from $T$ to $I$.
We actually have the following statement.

> **Proposition.**
> Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a category with initial object $I$ and terminal object $T$.
> The following conditions on $I$ and $T$ are equivalent:
>
> 1. The object $I$ is also terminal in $\mathcal{C}$.
> 2. The object $T$ is also initial in $\mathcal{C}$.
> 3. The unique morphism from $I$ to $T$ is an isomorphism.
> 4. There exists a morphism from $T$ to $I$.

If one (and thus all) of these equivalent conditions are satisfied, then one calls the initial object of $\mathcal{C}$ (which is then also its terminal object) a zero object.
Some examples of this:

- In $\mathbf{Grp}$, the trivial group is a zero object.
- Given a ring $R$, the zero module is a zero object in $R\text{-}\mathbf{Mod}$.

---

> From the definitions of initial and terminal objects, every object $A$ has unique morphisms $I \to A$, and $A \to T$.
> But unless $I$ and $T$ are the same (zero) object, then won't I have a distinct morphism from $I \to A \to T$ for every object $A$ through composition?

No, the morphisms $I \to A \to T$ don’t need to be distinct.

Let us denote the unique morphism from $I$ to $A$ by $f_A$ and the unique morphism from $A$ to $T$ by $g_A$.
The composite $g_A ∘ f_A$ is a morphism from $I$ to $T$, and there is only one such morphism.
This means that the composite $g_A ∘ f_A$ must be the same for every object $A$.

Let us look at an explicit example:

- For every ring $R$, the unique homomorphism of rings $f_R$ from $ℤ$ to $R$ is given by $f_R(n) = n ⋅ 1_R$ for every integer $n$.
  The unique homomorphism of rings $g_R$ from $R$ to $0$ (the zero ring) is the constant map $r \mapsto 0$.
  The composite $g_R ∘ f_R$ is the map
  $$
    ℤ \to 0 \,, \quad n \mapsto 0 \,.
  $$
  It doesn’t matter which ring $R$ we choose, the resulting homomorphism $ℤ \to R \to 0$ is always the same.

---

¹ Given a partially ordered set $P$, the corresponding category $\mathcal{P}$ is defined as follows:
The objects of $\mathcal{P}$ are the elements of $P$.
For every two elements $x$ and $y$ of $P$, there exists at most one morphism from $x$ to $y$ in $\mathcal{P}$, and this morphism exists if and only if $x ≤ y$.
The composition of morphisms in $\mathcal{P}$ is defined in the only possible way.